# How to create multiple popup using with same name of "data-target" attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap to create multiple popup models using data-target attribute.

Like:

```
<a class="result-right-icon" id="createNewFolder" data-target="#Favorites_Modal" data-toggle="modal" href="" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">Favorites</a>


<a class="result-right-icon" data-target="#recentview_Modal" data-toggle="modal" href="" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">Recent View</a>




 <div class="modal fade" id="Favorites_Modal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm sr_popup">

       <div class="modal-content sr_popup_content">
          <div class="modal-header sr_pop_heading">

          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
           <a id="createNewFolder" data-target="">Open Popup </a>
          </div>
       </div>

    </div>
 </div>


     <div class="modal fade" id="recentview_Modal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm sr_popup">

       <div class="modal-content sr_popup_content">
          <div class="modal-header sr_pop_heading">

          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
           <a id="createNewFolder" data-target="">Open Popup </a>
          </div>
       </div>

    </div>
 </div>
```

Now Working fine but i  don’t want use multiple data-target attribute and multiple popup model div.

I try to  use only one data-target attribute name of all popup needed , and i want to replace my popup content with ajax response.

Now i am try to replace my response to existing popup , but did failed.

```
$(document).delegate('#createNewFolder', 'click', function(){ 
        createNewSaveDocFoldView(); 
}); 
function createNewSaveDocFoldView(){ 
        jQuery.post(createNewFoldURL).success(function(response){ 
                //$('#Favorites_Modal').html(""); 
                $('#Favorites_Modal').empty(""); 
                $('#Favorites_Modal').html(response); 
        }).error(function(){ 
        }); 
}
```

Comment: whats the error? what does "failed" means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to trigger the DOM click event after this line:

```
$('#Favorites_Modal').html(response); 
$('#createNewFolder')[0].click(); // <-----this would trigger it.
```

I am not sure if `.delegate()` method is working. Instead the preferred way to event delegation is done by `.on()` method:

```
$(document).on('click', '#createNewFolder', createNewSaveDocFoldView);

function createNewSaveDocFoldView(){ 
    jQuery.post(createNewFoldURL).success(function(response){ 
            //$('#Favorites_Modal').html(""); 
            $('#Favorites_Modal').empty(""); 
            $('#Favorites_Modal').html(response); 
            $('#createNewFolder')[0].click(); // <-----this would trigger it.
    }).error(function(){ 
    });


}
```

Comment: i try to open <a id="createNewFolder" data-target="#Favorites_Modal">Open Popup </a> in second popup the first popup model should be closed

Comment: $('#createNewFolder')[0].click(); why use ?pls explain

Comment: @GobinathMahalingam twitter Bootstrap's modal needs a DOM click not the jQuery's click and appending index with brackets converts jq object to Dom element and then you can fire the Dom click event. That element is similar like `document.getElementById(id) == $('#id')[0]`.